# How can I solve undefined index in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show payments like this:

[image]

And my payments table structure:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
 $months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
 $collection = App\Payment::all();
 $payments = $collection->groupBy('student_id');
 return view('payment', compact('payments', 'months'));
```

And my blade code is:

```
@foreach($payments as $payment)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $payment['student_id'] }}</th>
    @foreach($months as $month)
    <td>
        <i class="{{ $month == $payment['month'] ? 'fa fa-check text-success' : 'fa fa-times text-danger' }} "></i>
    </td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I got undefined index error. But when I add $payment[0]['student_id'] and $payment[0]['month'] this. I don't get any error. But I don't get exactly that I want.

Comment: Check for the existence of `$payment['month']` with `isset`.

Comment: You can bebug your code by yourself, you groupBy ... so you have an array of arrays, look here and debug : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: I tried to return $payment and I got this. Plese see this https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2020/4/14/cc9f663957d4b2a7a9e53638afba7b98-full.png

Comment: $payment['month'] it does not exist

Comment: can you add `dd($payments);` in the controller before returning the view ? and show us the result

Comment: I tried to dd($pyment) and this is the screenshot https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2020/4/14/a75b34fa0637d74e1d25d47e654e0d80-full.png

Comment: Nice, then check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this :

```
@foreach($payments as $key => $value)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $key }}</th>
    @foreach($months as $month)
        <td>
            <i class="{{ in_array($month, $value->pluck('month')->all()) ? 'fa fa-check text-success' : 'fa fa-times text-danger' }} "></i>
        </td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In the Contoroller you get the data like this :

```
[
    'ID1' => [
        ['student_id' => 'ID1', 'month' => 'JAN' ...],
        ['student_id' => 'ID1', 'month' => 'FEB' ...],
    ],
    'ID2' => [
        ['student_id' => 'ID2', 'month' => 'APR' ...],
    ],
]
```

That's why i did the key value loop to get the student_id as key and the payments of that student as values, the we pluck the months to get an array of months that the given student payed

```
['JAN', 'FEB'] // for the student with ID1
```

Then the `in_array` method test if the current month in the loop of months exist in the payed ones of the student if yes show succes else show danger.

Comment: happy to help :) if you want some explaination i can explain :)

Comment: Yes. Please describe.

Comment: Yes. I understand. Thank a lot. You are really great.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain check this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211655/laravel-help if you want talk more about some other help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your controller

```
$months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
 $payments = App\Payment::orderBy('student_id','ASC')->get();
 return view('payment', compact('payments', 'months'));
```

Try this in your blade file

```
@foreach($payments as $payment)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $payment->student_id }}</th>
    @foreach($months as $month)
    <td>
        <i class="{{ $month == $payment->month ? 'fa fa-check text-success' 
          : 'fa fa-times text-danger' }} "></i>
    </td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get this new error Property [student_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Still get same error. Please see this screenshot .https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2020/4/14/cc9f663957d4b2a7a9e53638afba7b98-full.png

Comment: I edited the answer @ShahadatHossain please try that

Comment: This is working but not exactly. Because there three rows. But i want only one row for one student_id